# How can I get Linux apps to work on Chromium on a Lenovo Ideapad?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, lenovo-laptop, chromium, chromebook

I converted a new Lenovo Ideapad running Win 10 to the latest version of Chromium OS.

I tied to initiate Linux apps, but there is an error when the installation gets to the point where it is creating a VM.

A VM app appears in my dock, but when I initiate the app, I get the following error:

[==== ] Starting the virtual machine Error starting penguin container: 5 Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 5

I have tried to reboot Chromium and I've switched channels, using Stable, Beta, and Dev., but I get the same error.

I tried to powerwash Chromium since this was recommended in other posts on the Internet, but hitting [cntl][alt][shift][T] did not bring up the powerwash option.

So I rebooted the machine, booting off a USB drive, essentially a new installation, and received the same errors.

Has anyone seen this before?

I don't know if it's a software problem, an environmental problem, or a hardware problem, since I don't know if a Lenovo Ideapad supports a fully functioning Chromiumbook.

Thank you